# How to create funnel with event's parameter value in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a game with a lot of levels (Something like 2000). I want to create a funnel to see players' progression through these levels and balance out too-hard ones.

I cannot send an unique event for every level (e.g. "Level 0040 Completed") because 
Firebase has a limit of 500 unique events. So I need to send an event like "Level Completed" and send the level number as parameter. But I don't know how can I create a funnel with that parameter. Is there any way to create funnel with a parameter of an event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to make it a funnel? You could log level_started/completed/failed, check how many attempts the users make before giving up, how much time they spend in the level etc, and figure it out that way.

Realistically you will have to connect your Firebase instance to BigQuery to do this though.

Comment: So if I add level_started, level_completed, level_failed with level number as a parameter, Is it possible to see how many people started level X, and how many of them failed, and how many of them won?

Comment: I'd rather not use BigQuery if it's possible. because you need to write code to see data. I want something to be easy-to-use for designers.

Comment: You will be able to see how many times a level was started/completed/failed and by how many users, but it probably won't be very flexible or easy to work with. Basically you will have to go in each event and scroll through a list with 2000 rows. I still recommend the BigQuery approach since this gives you more insight. It helps if you know some basic SQL but you can also connect Google Datastudio to BigQuery and work with the data visually.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Google Analytics.

In **Explore** tab create a new **Funnel exploration** and specify your events and parameter values in **STEPS** layout.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Daniil Pavlenko's answer:

In the **funnel exploration**,  add **Steps**, then click **edit steps** (pencil icon) and select the event whereafter you can include a parameter as a filter to each specfic step in the funnel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).